# powershell Save text in out-file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$timeFromFile = Get-Content 'D:\script2\IIS\timeln.txt'

$diff = [datetime]::Now - [datetime]$timeFromFile

[System.Math]::Round($diff.TotalSeconds)

if ($diff.TotalSeconds -gt 900){
Write-Host "Time difference is greater than 900 seconds"
}   
$diff.TotalSeconds | Out-File 'D:\script2\IIS\EndTime.txt'
```

---

When the above script is executed, the result value for the calculated time is saved as EndTime.txt. However, when 900 seconds have passed, the message is not saved in the EndTime.txt file, only the time value is output. How to fix?

Comment: Generally, `Write-Host` is for printing to the _display_ (host), not for outputting data. Even if you switched that to `Write-Output` (or better yet, output the string directly), it wouldn't end up in your file, because it isn't part of what you're piping to `Out-File`.

Comment: What does `timeln.txt` contain?

Comment: I don't get it - your code works fine. It prints (as the code says) diff.TotalSeconds to the file. What should it do differently?

Comment: timeln.txt contains 11:00:03
Only the time is displayed like this

Comment: My guess is you shouldn't write the TotalSeconds time to the file, but the current date as parsable string. Something like `Get-Date -Format 'O' | Out-File 'D:\script2\IIS\timeln.txt'`. Then the next time, your calculation to get `$diff` will result in a valid TimeSpan object.

Comment: When the above script is executed, the result is only numbers ex) 39568.2052459
Do not record "Time difference is greater than 900 seconds"

Comment: Just remove the `Write-Output` in front of the message. As @mklement0 mentioned, check [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) for details on how to put something on the pipeline. You might also use `Tee-Object` to do both: display *and* put the message on the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment "*When the above script is executed, the result is only numbers ex) 39568.2052459 Do not record "Time difference is greater than 900 seconds*" I finally might have an idea on what you're after :)

What you have done is piped the seconds to file (`$diff.TotalSeconds | Out-File 'D:\script2\IIS\EndTime.txt'`) and you need to pipe the message itself. I added the seconds value in message.

```
$timeFromFile = [datetime]::Now

$diff = [datetime]::Now - [datetime]$timeFromFile

$diffSecs = [System.Math]::Round($diff.TotalSeconds)

#Initialize empty string variable for message
$msg = ""
if ($diffSecs -gt 900) {
    #Setting the message if greater than 900
    $msg = "Time difference is greater than 900 seconds ($diffSecs)"
}
else {
    #If lower or equal
    $msg = "Time difference IS NOT greater than 900 seconds ($diffSecs)"
}

#Setting the content of file to the $msg variable value
$msg | Out-File C:\Temp\asd.txt
```

Comment: you are a genius
Thank you